# How to send string with special characters as input to stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: string, oracle, stored-procedures

I have written a procedure which takes query as input, the query which i am trying to use for testing consist of single quotes(') when this query is run independently on Oracle developer it runs seamlessly. But when same query is passed in string format to execute procedure, i get invalid expression error.

To rectify this error i added double quotes('') wherever single quote was used, after this i got right parenthesis missing error. I even tried using CHR(39) which is an ASCII value of single quote but this also didn't gave any relief.

Is there any way i can pass query containing such types of special characters.

Query for reference:

```
select c1 as Order,c2 as lineId,
listagg(concat(concat(concat(tkey,' : '),concat(name,' : ')), status), ': ') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c2) AS status from ABC 
where 
name in ('XY','LM','GT','GZ','AB') 
AND 
c2 in(select distinct(c2) from LMN
where 
c1 in (select c1 from LMN 
where 
c1 > (select (cast ((systimestamp - numtodsinterval(1,'hour')) at time zone 'UTC' as date) - date '1970-01-01') * 86400 from dual) 
AND 
c1 < (select (cast (systimestamp at time zone 'UTC' as date) - date '1970-01-01') * 86400 from dual)) 
AND 
from_system is not null) GROUP BY c1,c2
```

Above query is passed as execute.proceudre_name('query')

PS
on using q-quote mechanism, query looks like:

```
execute getTransactionDetails(q'{select c1 as Order,c2 as lineId,
    listagg(concat(concat(concat(tkey,' : '),concat(name,' : ')), status), ': ') 
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c2) AS status from ABC 
    where 
    name in ('XY','LM','GT','GZ','AB') 
    AND 
    c2 in(select distinct(c2) from LMN
    where 
    c1 in (select c1 from LMN 
    where 
    c1 > (select (cast ((systimestamp - numtodsinterval(1,'hour')) at time zone 'UTC' as date) - date '1970-01-01') * 86400 from dual) 
    AND 
    c1 < (select (cast (systimestamp at time zone 'UTC' as date) - date '1970-01-01') * 86400 from dual)) 
    AND 
    from_system is not null) GROUP BY c1,c2;}');
```

getting error as:

```
Error starting at line : 3 in command -
listagg(concat(concat(concat(tkey,' : '),concat(name,' : ')), status), ': ')
Error report -
Unknown Command

SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
>>Query Run In:Query Result 1
```

Comment: You don't need `SELECT ... from dual` - Just use `c1 > cast ((systimestamp - numtodsinterval(1,'hour')) at time zone 'UTC' as date) - date '1970-01-01') * 86400`

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit for suggestion !!

Answer (score 0):

Use the q-quoting mechanism. Here's a simple example:

This is query which contains single quotes, and it'll be passed to the procedure:

```
SQL> SELECT sal FROM emp WHERE ename = 'KING';

       SAL
----------
     10000
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_test (par_query IN VARCHAR2)
  2  IS
  3     l_sal  emp.sal%TYPE;
  4  BEGIN
  5     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE par_query
  6        INTO l_sal;
  7
  8     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Salary = ' || l_sal);
  9  END;
 10  /

Procedure created.
```

How to call it? As I said - the q-quoting mechanism:

```
SQL> EXEC p_test(q'[select sal from emp where ename = 'KING']');
Salary = 10000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Apply it to your case. Note that I used square brackets; if *string* you're passing to the procedure contains them, you'll have to switch to something else, e.g. curly brackets.

Comment: Thanks @littlefoot for reply, i tried using q-quoting mechanism but that didn't worked it. I am getting error on listagg function post it's use. I have edited my answer. Can you please review it

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know why LISTAGG returns an error; you made it more complicated than you should (using nested CONCAT), so - try a simpler option, using the double pipe `||` concatenation operator: `LISTAGG (tkey || ' : ' || name || ' : ' || status, ': ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c2)`

Comment: Didn't thought of it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: If you get any solution for LISTAGG. kindly suggest :)

Comment: Nope, sorry. "Error message" you posted isn't descriptive at all. It would help if you could execute it in SQL*Plus; it'll reveal some more - hopefully useful - information.

Comment: The error message which i have shared is exact message i got on SQL developer

Comment: No doubt. I'm referring to "Error report - Unknown Command" ... really doesn't help. What "unknown command"? But, if you ran it in SQL*Plus, it marks the spot with an asterisk and actually tells you where to look at.